# ggplot2 barchart: how to set fill colours manually if zero counts are present

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create barcharts with **manual fill colors** using `ggplot2`.

```
library(ggplot2)
```

This works fine if there are no zero counts in any of the categories.

```
d <- data.frame(x=factor(1:7, levels=1:7))
g <- ggplot(d, aes(x=x)) +
  geom_bar(fill=rep(c("red", "blue"), length=7)) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE)
g
```

But if any of the counts are zero I get an error:

```
d2 <- data.frame(x=factor(1:6, levels=1:7))
g %+% d2

Error: Incompatible lengths for set aesthetics: fill
```

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change the way you're doing the fill:

```
d2 <- data.frame(x=factor(1:6, levels=1:7))
g <- ggplot(d2, aes(x=x)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=x)) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=rep(c("red", "blue"), length=7))
g
```

[image]